# Satzbildung mit "zum Ausdruck bringen/sich ausdrücken"

Tags: meaning

Liebe meine Experten,

sind die Formulierungen richtig?

1. "ich muss diese Ideen/das Thema bei meinem Chef zum Ausdruck bringen.= ich muss mich mit den Ideen bei meinem Chef ausdrücken. "
2. "du musst die Entscheidung treffen, ob du hier arbeitest oder nicht.= "du musst dich entscheiden, ob du hier arbeitest oder nicht."

Danke euch sehr

Answer (score 1):

Keinen dieser Sätze würde man im Deutschen verwenden.

Für 1. würde man sagen:

> Ich muss diese Ideen/das Thema bei meinem Chef ansprechen.

Für 2. würde man sagen:

> Du musst dich entscheiden, ob du hier arbeiten willst oder nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Zunächst möchte ich anmerken, daß ich nicht verstehe, warum man die - völlig zutreffende - Antwort von @TilmanSchmidt abwertet.

Darüber hinaus möchte ich noch ein paar Erläuterungen zu dieser Antwort anfügen:

*Ad 1.*: Das sind beides Sätze, die grammatikalisch korrekt sind, aber in keiner Weise dem "natürlichen Sprachgebrauch" entsprechen. So spricht niemand! Das bedeutet, man kann sie zwar durchaus verwenden, aber nur, wenn man einen besonderen, triftigen Grund dafür hat, sich genau so und nicht anders auszudrücken. Für den üblichen Gebrauch - man will einfach mitteilen, daß man seinem Chef was erzählen muß - ist Tilmans Vorschlag wesentlich besser geeignet. Hier sind noch ein paar Alternativen:

> Ich muß meinem Chef diese Ideen/das Thema **präsentieren**.
> Ich muß meinem Chef diese Ideen/das Thema **vortragen**.
> Ich muß meinem Chef diese Ideen/das Thema **aufbereiten**.

Zum nächsten Punkt:

> "Du musst dich entscheiden [die Entscheidung treffen], ob du hier arbeitest oder nicht."

Das geht nicht - undd zwar schon rein logisch nicht! "Hier arbeiten" ist ein Faktum und es stimmt entweder oder es stimmt nicht. Da gibt es nichts zu entscheiden. *Entscheiden* kann man sich nur, ob man das, was der Fall ist, auch tatsächlich *will*. Deshalb ist Tilmans Antwort absolut korrekt.